# I want to re execute the command used nth command ago and last command which name begins with m

Tags: bash, interactive-shell

I wanted to ree execute the command I executed nth command ago using the history command but I have no clue how to do it. and also I want to execute the last command I used which name begins with let's say 'm'.

Comment: Added _interactive-shell_ tag for clarification....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!-2` and `!m`.

See the chapter *HISTORY EXPANSION* in the bash man page.